# Hive select from two tables where fields match?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have two tables, both have `email` and `name` fields. How to write Hive query that will return all recocrds that have matching e-mails in both tables&

For example:

```
 Table_1 :
   name x, email e1 
   name y, email e2

Table_2:
  name z, email e3 
  name q, email e2

Result:
  name q, email e2
  name y, email e2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `JOIN`. Check this manual page on info about `JOINS`.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins

You can write a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.email = Table_2.email
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_3 ON Table_2.email = Table_3.email;
```

This query will return you all the records with matching emails.

Comment: Why LEFT JOIN, and not full join? For example: SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.email = tabel2.email)

Comment: Have used LEFT JOIN to cover the scenario of `NULL` record in the left tables, but if your data is normalized and there will not be any `NULL` scenarios, then you can use FULL JOIN.